# Error in building SQL statement

Tags: ormlite, query-builder

While running this code:

```
note = noteDAO.queryForFirst(
    noteDAO.queryBuilder().where().notIn("id",
        noteStateDAO.queryBuilder().distinct().selectColumns("noteId")
        .prepare())
    .prepare());
```

... I've got following exception:

```
Problems executing Android query: SELECT * FROM `notes` WHERE `id` NOT IN 
     (MappedStatement: SELECT DISTINCT `noteId` FROM `note_states`)
```

Any ideas of what is `MappedStatement` in that SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've solved you problem it seems, but I thought I'd provide some more information.

The `Where.notIn(...)` method takes either objects or a `QueryBuilder` argument.  By doing a `prepare()`, it turns it into a `MappedQuery` which was passed as an `Object` unfortunately.

As you mention, if your remove the `prepare()`, it will use the `QueryBuilder` arguments.  See the [javadocs for `notIn(String, QueryBuilder)`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/Where.html#notIn%28java.lang.String,%20com.j256.ormlite.stmt.QueryBuilder%29).

I've added better checking against passing in a prepared query in [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) version 4.43.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found by myself. No need to `prepare` the inner subselect query:

```
note = noteDAO.queryForFirst(
    noteDAO.queryBuilder().where().notIn("id",
        noteStateDAO.queryBuilder().distinct().selectColumns("noteId")
        /*.prepare()*/)
    .prepare());
```